# How can I set the footprint of my robot in nav2?

Tags: ros, ros2, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to set the footprint of my robot while using nav2. How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344468/how-can-i-set-the-footprint-of-my-robot-in-nav2?/) by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2020-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its the same as ROS1, in the costmap parameter configs give a list of ordered points to the footprint parameter, exclusive of the robot_radius parameter.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-18**:
On another topic- you seem to have alot of questions related to nav2. You may want to join us in our weekly working group meetings.

**Comment by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on 2020-02-18**:
I do not know if you are joking or not. If you are not joking I accept your invitation.

**Comment by [Carl D](https://answers.ros.org/users/36816/carl-d/) on 2020-02-18**:
He's not joking. We want to make nav2 better. We'd love to hear about how you are using it, and ways that we can improve it.

**Comment by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on 2020-02-19**:
I would be pleasured to participate. Could you give me the details?

**Comment by [Carl D](https://answers.ros.org/users/36816/carl-d/) on 2020-02-19**:
See the google calendar at the bottom of this page. https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Governance/ for the meeting invite.

The next meeting is tomorrow, Feb 20 at 2PM Pacific Time.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-20**:
Indeed. Also @lorenzo I'd love if you were able to write a tutorial page for our documentation about using the nav2_util lifecycle bringup scripts to launch lifecycle nodes from the commandline. I've seen in your ticket you've used it a couple times and I'm especially surprised to see users using it. If that's valuable, it would be exceedingly valuable to have a tutorials page on it

**Comment by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on 2020-02-21**:
If I will succeed I would be glad of writing a tutorial page about.